# Getting POST Request Message using React.JS

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, http-post, fetch, postman

I am writing a program which has a "sign up" functionality. The front-end is created using React.JS. So far, I am able to using this code to send a post request in React.JS:

```
fetch('http://localhost:2000/users/signup/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "email": "testing@gmail.com",
        "password": "secret",
        "name": "matthew",
        "organization": "Apple"
      })
}).then(function(response) {
 return response.json();
});
```

This works perfectly - for the user information is now in the database. However I am not sure how to get the response JSON using response.json(). I want to be able to take the response, get the message string, and display it to my user on the front-end. This is the response when I run the same post request on Postman.

```
{
    "message": "New user created"
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You already have the json... it's `response.json()` you should be able to just console.log it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise, so you need one more `then` to get the actual data:

```
.then(function(response) {
 return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
 console.log(data);
})
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: Okay got it -- do you know how I could display this response to the user on the front-end? Would I store this response in a variable?

Comment: Typically you would use `setState({whatever: data})` to store the value and then access it via `this.state.whatever`